# How to specify multiple resource conditions in Cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a Cloudformation template with 2 conditions

```
Conditions:
  ProdEnvironment:
    !Equals [ !Ref VPCStackNameParameter, 'ProductionVPC' ]
  CertExists:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref SslCertificateArn, '']]
```

How can I specify BOTH conditions in a resource I want to create? Something like

```
Resources:
  Alb:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Condition: ProdEnvironment !And CertExists <--- this gives error!
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why not define a new condition containing both other conditions?

Comment: @kichik, how do I do that, using the !And function? So "ProdAndCert: !And, - Condition: ProdEnvironment, - Condition: CertExists"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create one condition that does both.

```
Conditions:
  ProdEnvironment:
    !Equals [ !Ref VPCStackNameParameter, 'ProductionVPC' ]
  CertExists:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref SslCertificateArn, '']]
  CertExistsAndProd: !And
    - !Equals [ !Ref VPCStackNameParameter, 'ProductionVPC' ]
    - !Not [!Equals [!Ref SslCertificateArn, '']]
Resources:
  Alb:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Condition: CertExistsAndProd
```

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) seems to suggest you can also reference conditions in conditions. So you can also try:

```
Conditions:
  ProdEnvironment:
    !Equals [ !Ref VPCStackNameParameter, 'ProductionVPC' ]
  CertExists:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref SslCertificateArn, '']]
  CertExistsAndProd: !And
    - !Condition ProdEnvironment
    - !Condition CertExists
Resources:
  Alb:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Condition: CertExistsAndProd
```